# Total sum of an Array

Tags: javascript, arrays, foreach

I'm working on a problem that requires the running sum within the array. Example, an array with the values [1,2,3,4] should return [1,3,6,10] and an array that holds [3,1,2,10,1] should output [3,4,6,16,17]. Right now I am stumped on what I am missing for my answer. I am thinking that I should handle this recursively in some way, but I am not sure how to begin with that. In any case, this is my current solution

```
var runningSum = function(nums) {
    let result = [];
    nums.forEach(function(num, idx) {
         if (idx === 0) {
             result.push(num);
         } else {
             result.push(num + nums[idx - 1]);  
         }
    });
    return result;
}
```

Leet code stated that this was a fairly easy problem, so I figured that I'm thinking way too hard on this and can solve it a lot easier. Let me know your thoughts. Thanks!

Comment: change `num + nums[idx - 1]` to `num + result[idx - 1]` so that you actually take into the account the sum of previous numbers and not just the last number

Comment: Or do this: https://jsfiddle.net/ugmpvL9n/

Comment: Ah got it! Would it make sense to say that during the iteration, the nums array is represented by only one element?

Comment: You made it too complex: `function runningSum(nums) { let temp = 0; return nums.map(el => (temp += el, temp)); }` Example: https://wandbox.org/permlink/iOJnh6FR1cCBSu6z

Comment: @jabaa This works fine but writing to an external variable with .map() feels kind of icky to me ;)

Comment: @ChrisG Yes, to me too, but filling an array with `forEach` feels much more icky to me, especially when the input array and the output array have the same number of elements. Usually I would use a closure to hide the `temp` variable, but this function has only two lines of code. The function already is the closure.

Comment: If I know that I am returning a new array from the values, it feels as though .map() is more intuitive?

Comment: @jobaa1 Yes, but that's an opinion and a personal style.

Comment: @jabaa as well. I am fairly new and discussions/feedback like these help me process the material in more than one way.

Comment: @joA Discussions and opinions are off-topic on Stack Overflow.

Comment: @jabaa not exactly sure what you mean by that, but thank you again!

Answer (score 1):

A simpler (and more resource-friendly) way of approaching the problem would just be to use a `for` loop:

```js
/**
 * @param {number[]} nums
 * @return {number[]}
 */
var runningSum = function(nums) {
    for (let i = 1; i < nums.length; i++) nums[i] += nums[i-1];
    return nums;
};
```

Comment: Thank for you the response! When you say more resource-friendly, are you referring to space & time complexity? I am starting to learn more on this topic.

Comment: This modifes the input array. That's usually bad practice in JavaScript.

Comment: I was referring to performance tests done by others shown [here](https://leanylabs.com/blog/js-forEach-map-reduce-vs-for-for_of/). Other methods (such as `for`, `for...of`) perform relatively better than `.forEach()`.